# ASP.NET Core - call one controller method from another

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, controller

I need to call from create method delete for cleanup. I want to call `DeleteDevice` like lazy cleanup and do not care if it will succeed or not.

People suggested to use this way:

```
DeleteDevice(param).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Is it safe?

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Device>> CreateDevice([FromBody] CreateDeviceRequest request)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    try
    {
        var registeredDevice = await RegisterDevice(request.DisplayName);

        bool isCreatePrinterSucceed = false;

        try
        {
            var updatedDevice = await UpdateDevice(registeredDevice.Id);

            isCreatePrinterSucceed = true;

            return Ok(new DeviceReference
            {
                DisplayName = request.DisplayName,
                Id = updatedDevice.Id
            });
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!isCreatePrinterSucceed)
            {
                var param = new DeleteDeviceRequest()
                {
                    Id = registeredDevice.Id,
                    AzureUserBearerToken = request.AzureUserBearerToken
                };
                DeleteDevice(param).ConfigureAwait(false); ;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you're trying to achieve here and what you mean by whether the operation is _safe_?

Comment: Can you encapsulate this delete method? Call it directly when you use it.

Comment: If UpdateDevice will fail I trying to delete uncompleted device . "safe" - means - user will not see any side effects even if delete will not succeed and have exceptions.